# Preventing Cursor Move when Validation Fails

Tags: ios, swift, validation

I would like to implement validation in my view such that, when the user enters invalid text into a `UITextField`, all other `UITextField`s are disabled and the cursor remains in the current place. I am using the `SwiftValidator` library (https://github.com/jpotts18/SwiftValidator).

The validation of a text field is triggered by `UIControlEvent.EditingDidEnd`, which typically happens when the user moves to the next field. I have not been able to prevent the cursor moving to the other `UITextField` nor have I been able to get it back to the view that failed validation. What would be the right approach?

Below are the relevant sections of my code, where `validateSingleValue()` is the place where I'm trying to implement the logic for this task.

My `ViewController` acts as a delegate to my custom control groups, handling `EditingDidEnd` events. The custom controls are typically a `UILabel` and a `UITextField` embedded in a `UIView`.

```
func textViewEditingDidEnd(editTextPropertyGroup: EditTextPropertyGroup) {

    validateField(editTextPropertyGroup.propertyValue)

}
```

Fields are validated using

```
func validateField(sender: AnyObject) {
    switch (sender as! UITextField) {
    case firstNameField:
        validateSingleValue(textfield: firstNameField, validationrule: firstNameRule(), errorlabel: firstNameErrorLabel, container: firstNameField.superview)
    case lastNameField:
        validateSingleValue(textfield: lastNameField, validationrule: lastNameRule(), errorlabel: lastNameErrorLabel, container: lastNameField.superview)
    case adressField:
        validateSingleValue(textfield: addressField, validationrule: addressRule(), errorlabel: addressErrorLabel, container:  addressField.superview)
    case emailField:
        validateSingleValue(textfield: emailField, validationrule: emailRule(), errorlabel: emailErrorLabel, container: emailField.superview)
    default:
        print("No fields to validate.")
    }
}

func validateSingleValue(textfield textField:UITextField, validationrule validationRule: Rule, errorlabel errorLabel: UILabel, container: UIView?) -> Bool {

   if validationRule.validate(textField.text!) {
        errorLabel.hidden = true
        textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
        textField.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        enableAllControls()
        return true
    } else {
        errorLabel.hidden = false
        textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        textField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        if let unwrappedContainer = container {
            textField.becomeFirstResponder()
            disableAllControls()
            unwrappedContainer.userInteractionEnabled = true
            unwrappedContainer.alpha = 1.0
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

and for disabling and enabling the controls:

```
override func disableAllControls() {
    self.FirstNameSection.propertyValue.userInteractionEnabled = false
    self.FirstNameSection.alpha = 0.3
    self.LastNameSection.userInteractionEnabled = false
    self.LastNameSection.alpha = 0.3
    self.AddressSection.userInteractionEnabled = false
    self.AddressSection.alpha = 0.3
    self.EmailSection.userInteractionEnabled = false
    self.EmailSection.alpha = 0.3
}
override func enableAllControls() {
    self.FirstNameSection.propertyValue.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.FirstNameSection.alpha = 1.0
    self.LastNameSection.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.LastNameSection.alpha = 1.0
    self.AddressSection.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.AddressSection.alpha = 1.0
    self.EmailSection.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.EmailSection.alpha = 1.0
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that all this can be achieved with only a few lines of code. To support validation, the UITextFieldDelegate protocol defines the following methods:

```
textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_:)
textFieldDidBeginEditing(_:)
textFieldShouldEndEditing(_:)
textFieldDidEndEditing(_:)
```

(see documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/index.html))

The code in the question can be reduced to:

```
var shouldEndEdit: Bool = true

func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    validator.validateField(textField) { error in
        if error == nil {
            self.shouldEndEdit = true
        } else {
            self.shouldEndEdit = false
        }
    }
    return self.shouldEndEdit
}
```

plus the validation rules as described [here](https://github.com/jpotts18/SwiftValidator).

Answer (score 0):

Jerry, I did something like this many moons ago; this is a snippet of the code in objective C I fear, sorry.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

if ([textField.accessibilityIdentifier isEqualToString:@"ClassSize"]) {
    if ([self isNumeric:string]) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
return YES;
```

}

Basically if the user tried to input incorrect data, the keyboard didn't respond.

I used this technique to guard agains't number that were beyond a certain range and indeed even to restrict said user when entering a hexadecimal number I recall. They could only enter 0-F in the field.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this idea. It’s an interesting approach. In my case, input may be invalid at first and become valid with more characters entered (like in email addresses). One could do “as-you-type” validation, which is a similar idea. I have thought about that, but while your case is pretty clear to the user, my variation might be confusing. But I will keep that in mind as a backup, still hoping that plan A - getting that cursor under control - works out somehow.